# Override css over materializecss

Tags: html, css, styles

Since I have installed the materialize css. I am having trouble with a button that uses a custom class. I need to set this border to 0.

[image: the css]

Button Before :
[image: before]
Button After:
[image: after]

I have already tried :

```
[type="checkbox"][_ngcontent-eog-31]    + label[_ngcontent-eog-31]:before, [type="checkbox"][_ngcontent-eog-31]:not(.filled-in)    + label[_ngcontent-eog-31]:after {
  border:  0px, none!important;
}

and

checkbox{
border 0px, none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**border:  0px, none !important;** is a invalid property value, remove ( **,** ) in between **0px** and **none**

Try to give following code,

```
border: none !important;
```

Or

```
border: 0px !important;
```

Or

```
border: 0px none !important;
```

Comment: It didnt work  . I tried all of them with both checkbox and the bigger type

Answer (score 0):

The values given to the `border` shorthand property need to be provided in the form of a **space separated** list, not a comma separated one.

Remove the `,` between `0px` and `none`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Quentin but it was not enough. Maybe it is the class that is wrong, something with the ngcontent